# vb.net selecting option from combobox and displaying in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've been trying to find a solution since very long but no avail.

I'm trying to make my program such that when i select a code from a combobox,it should display a description related to that code in one textbox and display a number in another textbox. Once this is done,it should create another combobox on the next line with exactly the same items. E.g

```
Code            Description               cost           tax
1141            Replace battery           10.00          14.00
```

- All items under "code" are in a combobox for the user to select.
- If a user selects "1141",the program fills in the description "replace battery" and the cost only

I'm using VB.NET 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Generally,  you need to handle the `SelectedValueChanged` event on the `ComboBox`, and do a lookup of some sort to get the values to set into the `TextBoxes`.  For example, you could have an array of all your `SaleItem` objects (which would store `Code`, `Description`, `cost`, `tax`), and you'd search the array until you found a matching `Code`.